# Euler lagrange equations for a curve integral

Tags: integration, optimization, calculus-of-variations, computer-vision

I'm reading through [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.6.1793&rep=rep1&type=pdf), where a variational framework to some computer vision feature detection techniques is given. I'm familiar with variational techniques, though I'm not an expert. There's the following integral (formula (9) on the paper)

$$
E(\vec{n}) = \oint_{0}^L sign(\langle v, \nabla I \rangle) \langle \nabla I, \vec{n} \rangle ds
$$

It is claimed that the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation is given by

$$
sign(\langle v, \nabla I \rangle) \Delta I = 0
$$

Where $\Delta $ is the laplacian operator.
In the above integral $I$ is a 2D image, $\vec{n}$ is the normal to some curve $\gamma$ that we want to find, $v$ is vector orthogonal to the level set.

I'm quite confused how the Euler lagrange equations might be derived, and I don't actually know where I can start. Either an explanation or just a clue would be useful,

thank you.

Comment: Did you read the paper? It is clear and sound in the derivation of the EL equations! What the step you miss?

Comment: I might be blind, but where exactly is the derivation of the equation above?

Comment: Unfortunately in the paper, the equations are not numbered. The above equations are a consequence of considering $\rho(\alpha) = |\alpha|$ (half left column, third page)

Comment: So the derivation is in section II ?

Comment: Yes. It is in section II

Comment: I'll read through, and I'll eventually post un update.

Comment: I'm reading through the derivation, I've also realized the paper I posted is a different version from the one I'm actually reading. The most similar equation I can see in the paper is $$\frac{\delta \psi}{\delta C} = sign(\langle v, \nabla I \rangle) \Delta I \bf{n}, $$ if  I wanted to find the minimum I'd set $$sign(\langle v, \nabla I \rangle) \Delta I \bf{n} = 0.$$ Does the equation follow from a) $\bf{n}$ isn't the zero vector and b) it must bu the scalar $sign(\langle v, \nabla I \rangle) \Delta I = 0$ ?